# Use of PHP script in a jquery function

Tags: javascript, php

I've echoed the following php and it shows up properly in HTML so that can't be a problem:

PHP

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

//create the drop down menu
 $list ="";
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $list = '<div class="dropOption">'.$row["item"].'</div>';
 }
```

This outputs three rows - apple, pear, strawberry - in the right div format.

And when I put the following php script into the jquery function below, the menu does contain the value strawberry (the last), however the first two are missing.

JavaScript

```
//drop down menu
$(document).ready(function(){
function createDropdown(){
    var drop = $('#customDropdown');
    var i;
    var htmlString = '<div id="dropContainer">';

    htmlString += '<?php echo $list;?>';

    htmlString += '</div>';
    drop.append(htmlString);
    }

   createDropdown();
```

I'm new to jquery and php so forgive me if the error is simple; however I'm pretty sure it's right, functionally speaking, because I'm getting something; so I figured the syntax must get be wrong somewhere.  Can anybody help?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your php it should be

`$list .= '<div class="dropOption">'.$row["item"].'</div>';`

and then output just like this `<?=$list;?>` in your js part

`.` is used to concatenate strings in php

Comment: like this you mean -  $list = '<div class="dropOption">".$row["item"]."</div>'; if so, it didn't seem to work

Comment: I mean leave it as it was in your JS part and add '.' in your php part as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Please note, the echo part is still needed in the output, before the variable list.

Answer (score 1):

You're only assigning the last item to the `$list` variable. You need to concatenate them all together.

Try:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // Create the drop down menu
    $list = "";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $list .= '<div class="dropOption">' . $row["item"] . '</div>';
    }
}
```

Note the `$list .=` instead of `$list =` part.